# I prevented you from going there

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, complements, object-complements

> - I prevented you **from going there**.

What is the function of "*from going there*" ?

I think that it is an *adverbial* prepositional phrase because I have studied object complements and learned that object complements can be adjectives, adjective phrases, infinitive clauses, nouns, verb+ing forms, but I've never seen a prepositional phrase as an object complement.

So, I think that it is an adverbial prepositional phrase and that's why it can be placed in the beginning. Because we know that adverbial prepositional phrases can be located in the beginning.

> From going there, I prevented you.

What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: It is a complement of the verb, but does not modify the object: it designates the action which was prevented.

Comment: [Put it at the beginning, you can.](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/yoda-grammar) But it would sound strange outside of a Star Wars film. (This is the second time I've seen this kind of language discussed today.)